# R: Add a arrow on a circular barplot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a phenology figure using ggplot2, currently is looking like this:
[Circular barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkYgk.png)

Now I want to add an arrow that represents the mean angle (with "o = angle " and "r = magnitude"), like this [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZ8lB.png) ([Dahua-Machoa et al., 2018, p. 70](http://327714903_Temporalidad_de_fenofases_y_micropropagacion_in_vitro_de_tres_especies_relictuales_de_Magnolia_del_Occidente_de_Mexico_implicaciones_para_su_conservacion_in_situ_y_ex_situ)). I find a way to add a line using geom_vline() and a linear interpolation to graph it in the correct angle but I can't find a way to modify its length and give it an arrow-like form.

It's possible to do it with ggplot2?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code.

```
   Mes<-c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov"
      , "Dec")
mess<-(seq(1,12,1))
FlbudBr<-c(0,12,25,44,32,5,12,1,4,56,11,10)
dg<-c(15, 45,75,105,135,165,195,225,255,285,315,345)
data<-data.frame(Mes,mess,FlbudBr,dg)
library(NISTunits)
data$cos<-cos(NISTdegTOradian(data$dg))
data$sin<-sin(NISTdegTOradian(data$dg))
x<-sum(data$FlbudBr*data$cos)/sum(data$FlbudBr)
y<-sum(data$FlbudBr*data$sin)/sum(data$FlbudBr)
r<-sqrt((x)^2+(y)^2)
o<-180-NISTradianTOdeg(acos(x/r))

library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)


ggplot(data, aes(mess, FlbudBr)) +
  coord_polar() +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "#F8C471", color ="black", width = 0.8) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:12, labels = data$Mes, expand = c(.007,0)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = seq(0, 15, by = 5), color = "gray90", alpha= 0.4) +
  geom_vline(xintercept= ((139.57-135)/(150-135)*(5.5-5)+5))+
  ylab("Fl bud Br")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
        panel.border = element_blank())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `annotate`. Specify the line length with `yend`. `arrow = arrow()` will add the arrow heads.

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(mess, FlbudBr)) +
  coord_polar() +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "#F8C471", color ="black", width = 0.8) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:12, labels = data$Mes, expand = c(.007,0)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = seq(0, 15, by = 5), color = "gray90", alpha= 0.4) +
  ylab("Fl bud Br")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
        panel.border = element_blank())
```

```
arrow_x <- ((139.57-135)/(150-135)*(5.5-5)+5)

p + annotate(
  "segment",
  x = arrow_x,
  xend = arrow_x, 
  y = 0,
  yend = 25,
  colour = "red",
  size = 1,
  arrow = arrow()
)
```

[image: plot]